# Hourly cron job to save json data

Tags: json, cron

I would like to create a cron job which saves json data from an external url, hourly, to a mysql database. (http://dvcticker.bugs3.com/json-data.php)

I'm new to cron, so this is pretty much all I have:

0 * * * *

Sorry for my limited knowledge and thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: Your cron syntax is correct. Just put the command to run after that. It's pretty much the same syntax as if you were typing it to the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0 * * * * your-script.php`

You will need to set up an internal script to call the outbound URL for processing.

PHP example:

```
<?php
// your-script.php
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://dvcticker.bugs3.com/json-data.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // connect to database and save $data to your table
?>
```

Bookmark this url. It is a cron tab generator. very useful.

http://cron.nmonitoring.com/cron-generator.html

Comment: You can't run a URL from `cron`. It has to be a valid shell command.

Comment: you're right. I also failed to give the right syntax. I'll fix that.

Comment: Actually barmar posted the right answer. I just fixed mine after he commented and added an example.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
0 * * * * * /path/to/yourprogram
```

where `yourprogram` is the program (which could be a script in any language you like) that downloads the JSON data and puts it into your database.